# How to retrieve image file from Parse in PHP?

Tags: php, database, image, file, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse.com library for PHP via Composer as per the documentation.  I need to retrieve a file which may or may not exist from the Parse database, and clear it if it does exist.

Currently I did:

```
if ( $myObject->get("image") != "undefined" ) $myObject->set("image","");
```

I have been told that getData is used here but it has the same White Screen Of Death 
(tm) when I use that.

Can anyone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Bumping because originally posted with tag Parse instead of Parse.php - sorry.

Comment: The 'white screen of death' sounds like you have an error. Have you checked your logs?

Comment: I don't see myObject is error.log but it's possible I'm in the wrong place.  Is there a path where another log file is that I might need to try?

Comment: It might not mention `$myObject` by name, but it should log an error. The location of this depends on your Apache configuration - it is normally in /var/log/apache2/error.log or (I think) /etc/apache2/logs/error.log.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with PHP in a long time, so forgive me if this is wrong. Would you try this?

```
if ($myObject->get("image") != null) {
    $myObject->set("image", null);
    $myObject->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The problem with this is that the get function seems to have to be run against the file object itself.  So in other words I asked the question wrong and it should have been "$myObject->fileObject->get()" even though I didn't realize that at the time.  Sorry about that.  So obviously, if no fileObject exists to run the Parse call against, PHP throws a hissyfit.  If curious this is the data type that's being used: https://parse.com/docs/php_guide#files

Comment: Another problem you had was that you forgot to call save(). Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: I'm afraid not.  The problem here is that I'm getting a white screen of death, not that the data fails to appear.

Comment: This should delete the image from Parse, is that what you were trying to code or did I misunderstand?

Comment: The problem is the necessity of indirect referencing of the file object by the encapsulation object.  You have $mainObject which runs a query.  One of the returned fields *might be* a file object.  If that file object is empty, doing $mainObject->fileObject->get will always fail when fileObject is null.

Comment: What do you mean "one of the returned fields might be a file object"? If you write a query, it should return all the columns from that table. Could you further explain your question and possibly give more of your code.